# Exporting emails from Outlook - comma in subject line

Tags: outlook, outlook-2010

I'm trying to export email from Outlook(2010) into a CSV file, but there are emails with a comma in the subject line.
Is there a way to deal with this? I can't find an option to change the delimiter to something else.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the VBA Replace function.

Eg, this takes myString and replaces the comma with a dash.

```
Dim myString As String
myString = "Test subject, with comma"
myString = Replace(myString, ",", "-")
```

myString becomes "Test subject- with comma"

Answer (score 0):

If the value contains a comma, enclose the value in quotes. If you have a quote, replace it with a double quote. E.g a value like

```
Weird, encoded "subject"
```

becomes

```
"Weird, encoded ""subject"""
```